# Conditional expectation of Markov process, is it correct?

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Let $N$ be a Markov process where $N(0)=0$ with state space $S=\{0,1\}$ and $1$ is absorbing. Let $\mu(t) =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\mathbb{P}[N(t+h)=1|N(t)=0]}{h}$ be the transition rate from $0$ to $1$. Let $f$ be a function and $\tau$ the first time $N$ jumps to $1$.

Let $t\geq 0$ and denote by $N^t$ the stopped process $N$, this means $N^t=N(s)\mathbb{I}_{\{s\leq t\}}+N(t)\mathbb{I}_{\{s\geq t\}}$.

What is then the following conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)|N^t]$?

My attempt was
$$\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)|N^t]=\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)|N(t)=0](1-N(t))+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)|N(t)=1]N(t),$$
and from here I can continue, but I am not sure.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, if $\tau\le t$, then $\mathsf{N}^t$ contains all the information of $\tau$, and if $\tau>t$, then $\mathsf{N}^t$ contains only the information that $\tau>t$.
This motivates the conditional expectation
$$
 \mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid \mathsf{N}^t]
 =f(\tau){1}_{\{\tau\le t\}}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]{1}_{\{\tau>t\}}.
$$
Let's check that it's correct.
The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathsf{N}^t$ is generated by sets of the form $\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=0\}$ and $\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=1\}$ for $s\ge0$, so we must check that our proposal integrates the same as $f(\tau)$ on these sets.
Hence, let $s\ge0$ be given, and assume first that $s\le t$.
Then $\mathsf{N}^t_s=\mathsf{N}_s$, and we have $\{\mathsf{N}_s=0\}=\{\tau>s\}$ and $\{\mathsf{N}_s=1\}=\{\tau\le s\}\subseteq\{\tau\le t\}$.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=0\}}f(\tau){1}_{\{\tau\le t\}}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]{1}_{\{\tau>t\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
 &=\int_{\{s<\tau\le t\}}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]\mathbb{P}(\tau>t)
 =\int_{\{\tau>s\}}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\quad\text{and} \\
 \int_{\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=1\}}f(\tau){1}_{\{\tau\le t\}}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]{1}_{\{\tau>t\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
 &=\int_{\{\tau\le s\}}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}.
\end{align*}
If $s>t$ then $\mathsf{N}_s^t=\mathsf{N}_t$, $\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=0\}=\{\tau>t\}$ and $\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=1\}=\{\tau\le t\}$, and so
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=0\}}f(\tau){1}_{\{\tau\le t\}}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]{1}_{\{\tau>t\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
 &=\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]\mathbb{P}(\tau>t)
 =\int_{\{\tau>t\}}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\quad\text{and} \\
 \int_{\{\mathsf{N}_s^t=1\}}f(\tau){1}_{\{\tau\le t\}}+\mathbb{E}[f(\tau)\mid\tau>t]{1}_{\{\tau>t\}}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
 &=\int_{\{\tau\le t\}}f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P},
\end{align*}
and we see that our ansatz was correct.

Comment: So I was wrong then, but what you say (and then proof) is really intuitive actually. Thanks a lot!